# Isekai manga where a guy is sent to another world of magic and sword

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The manga is about a guy who is reincarnated to another world of magic and swords. He was born to a noble family. This guys is like a [Chuunibyou](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Chuunibyou#:~:text=Chuunibyou%20(%E4%B8%AD%E4%BA%8C%E7%97%85%20%2F%20%E5%8E%A8,Syndrome%22%20in%20US%20media).), and he tries to make a organization of shadow (I forgot the name because this was also the manga title). He picked a girl and a bunch to make an organization.

This guy likes to look like he's weak despite really OP and what I like is when he got duel with a girl, he uses mob technique to make him look weak, really weak.

Comment: What is "MOB TECHNIQUE"?

Comment: Death Mage seems like a partial match other than the noble family.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [Kage no Jitsuryokusha ni Naritakute](https://mangadex.org/title/33085/kage-no-jitsuryokusha-ni-naritakute), also known as *To Be a Power in the Shadows!*

The main character picks up girls and they end up making an organization.  The main character  uses 'mob techniques' to try to avoid standing out.  In the duel with the girl he used these to make himself look weak, however using them made him gain the attention of the girl because he kept standing up after being beaten.